# Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException using laravel 4

Tags: php, image, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using **laravel 4** and I installed the ***Intervention Image package***. When I'm using it in my code whith **method** -*>resize, ->move* etc etc etc... I have this **error:**

```
Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException
```

**Image source not readable**

```
open: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myNameProject/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractSource.php

        break;

        case $this->isFilePath():
            return $this->initFromPath($this->data);
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception\NotReadableException("Image source not readable");
            break;
    }
```

I'm also using **MAMP and Sublime Text 3 on MAC OS if it could help you.**

**This is my code in my controller:**

```
public function upload() {

//***** UPLOAD FILE (on server it's an image but an Url in Database *****//

// get the input file
$file = Image::make('url_Avatar');

//set a register path to the uploaded file
$destinationPath = public_path().'upload/';

//have client extension loaded file and set a random name to the uploaded file, produce a random string of length 32 made up of alphanumeric characters [a-zA-z0-9]
$filename = $destinationPath . '' . str_random(32) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
//$file->move($destinationPath,$filename);

//set $file in order to resize the format and save as an url in database
$file= Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('200','200')->save('upload/'.$filename);

//*****VALIDATORS INPUTS and RULES*****
$inputs = Input::all();
$rules = array(
'pseudo' => 'required|between:1,64|unique:profile,pseudo',
//urlAvatar is an url in database but we register as an image on the server
'url_Avatar' => 'required|image|min:1',
);
```

*(I don't show you the redirect of my view, but it's worked fine for this section of my controller)*

**here is my form code (using blade laravel template):**

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('title')
Name Of My Project - EditProfile
@stop

@section('content')
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'uploadAvatar','files' => true))}}

<p>
{{Form::label('pseudo','pseudo (*): ')}}
{{Form::text('pseudo',Input::old('nom'))}}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('pseudo'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('pseudo')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>

<p>
{{Form::label('url_Avatar','Avatar: ')}}
{{Form::file('url_Avatar',Input::old('Url_Avatar'))}}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('url_Avatar'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('url_Avatar')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>

<p>
{{Form::submit('Validate your avatar')}}
</p>

{{Form::close()}}
@stop
```

Of course I have installed **Intervention Image package** *following* the official website ***image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation*** (url).

How can I make my file **"readable"?** or resolve this error?

Comment: Show your code and make sure your  image location on the server is `readable/writable`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I've edited my code. How can I make my image location `readable/writable` ?

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I checked your answer. This has solved my problem partially. I have made a composer update, and I finalized my code, taking care to put your suggestion. Check my comment of your answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change this:

```
$file = Image::make('url_Avatar');
```

To this:

```
$file = Input::file('url_Avatar');
// ...
$filename = '...';
Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize('200','200')->save($filename);
```

Read more about [file on Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files).

Comment: Indeed, **I change the line** you suggest me into `$file = Input::file('url_Avatar');`. I have **also change** the line `$file= Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('200','200')->save('upload/'.$filename);` **into** `Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize('200','200')->save($filename);`. It works well. **Thank you for the help, your answer guided me to make this feature.**

Comment: I have a similar problem. I also edit my code as pointed out by you but it still gives me the same error message. Can you please have a look at [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139845/edit-image-source-not-readable-in-intervention-laravel) and help me out?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. I need to make image from url. Using Input::file() we can make image from input type file only. But in my case input is url. So How can I?

Comment: Have you tried `$image = Image::make('http://someurl.com/image.png')->save('/path/ImageName.png');` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. When I change image driver everything works fine.

Try to change image driver from app/config/packages/intervention/image/config.php from GD to Imagick

If you cant find config file try to run commands below:

**Publish configuration in Laravel 5**

$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"

**Publish configuration in Laravel 4**

$ php artisan config:publish intervention/image

Example content from config file:

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Image Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Intervention Image supports "GD Library" and "Imagick" to process images
    | internally. You may choose one of them according to your PHP
    | configuration. By default PHP's "GD Library" implementation is used.
    |
    | Supported: "gd", "imagick"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'imagick'

);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use a sub-folder in your public path, use chmod to change the permission on that folder
e.g
`cd public;
chmod -Rv 755 public/{your_path_name};`

Run

```
man chmod;
```

for more details

Answer (score 0):

this in solution

```
$filename = str_slug($products->name)."-0.jpg";
$filename_fb = 'fb-'.$filename;
$filename_tw = 'tw-'.$filename;

$img = Image::make($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
// resize image
$img->resize(800, 400);
// save image
$img->save($path.'/'.$filename);
```