# GD (PHP) failing with bad JPEG image resize (Laravel Intervention\Image), no error in error.log

Tags: php, laravel, gd, intervention

I'm running Apache/PHP 5.6 on both a Windows and Ubuntu dev box.  Using Laravel 5.1 and Intervention/Image with the GD driver, I'm trying to resize some pretty large images (15-25MB) the problem is the resize is failing with the error `Unable to read image from file (/tmp/phpxxxxxx)`, but only on large images.  Anything in the 5-10MB range has no problem resizing...

I'm assuming it has something to do with the process running out of memory (as smaller files have no issue), however the problem is I'm not actually getting any error messages at all in error.log...

I've increased `memory_limit` in my php.ini to 2000M for testing, but the resize still fails.

The code in the controller to resize the image is...

```
$img = Img::make($file->getRealPath());
```

The details of the error reported through Laravel are below...

```
NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 46:
Unable to read image from file (C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp\php361F.tmp).
in Decoder.php line 46
at Decoder->initFromPath('C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp\php361F.tmp') in AbstractDecoder.php line 293
at AbstractDecoder->init('C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp\php361F.tmp') in AbstractDriver.php line 64
at AbstractDriver->init('C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp\php361F.tmp') in ImageManager.php line 50
at ImageManager->make('C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp\php361F.tmp') in Facade.php line 216
at Facade::__callStatic('make', array('C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp\php361F.tmp')) in SubmitPhotoController.php line 97
at Image::make('C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp\php361F.tmp') in SubmitPhotoController.php line 97
at SubmitPhotoController->store()
```

How would I go about further troubleshooting to find out why this is failing?

NOTES:

1. I've decreased `memory_limit` just to make sure a low value would show an error when resizing and it does, so I don't think it's a PHP memory issue.
2. I DO see the file showing up in C:\Apache24\htdocs\tmp before quickly going away.

EDIT:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
```

EDIT 2:
After doing some testing, the images that were failing were those that were created by the panorama feature on my cell phone.  Even smaller file sized images ended up failing.

Comment: Better use your code on a linux server ,i have seen a lot of strage errors using windows LAMP.Also for large images and video processing I use ffmpeg to do this part .

Comment: @DionisL exact same error on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP7.  Just replace `C:\Apache24\htdocs` with `/tmp/phpxxxxx`

Comment: Could it be running out of time? Check `max_execution_time` in php.ini

Comment: @PatrickMoore, max_execution_time=60 however the actual upload\resize takes only seconds before the error

Comment: @DionisL I appreciate the suggestion, but trying to debug this error before moving to something different (which will probably end up being imagemagick eventually)

Comment: Php gd is good , but in production ,is good for small images not for ones that are very big , php being a script that runs under apache is better to put the work of resizing images to a special tool like ffmpeg

Comment: Yes , I hope you find the error cause I'm curious too . I'll keep an eye here to see how is resolved

Comment: Either of these help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195028/intervention-image-exception-notreadableexception-using-laravel-4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468437/getting-error-notreadableexception-in-abstractdecoder-php-line-302

Comment: Also wondering if your form has a hidden input MAX_FILE_SIZE value?

Comment: @PatrickMoore it does not have `MAX_FILE_SIZE` set in the form

Comment: @PatrickMore, I looked over those links, don't think that's the issue as it does work correctly for moderately sized images. But that does give me a little troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Stupid question, was Apache service restarted after max post/max upload size values changed?

Comment: Not a stupid question (because I've made that mistake before.....) But yes it was.

Comment: @dangel if you really want to debug this, save a big  image somewhere on your server and try to resize it, thus you eliminate all the http request stuff, If it works, then something's wrong with your form/requests, if it doesn't then something's wrong with your core php/gd/server setup

Comment: @vitr It's failing even with a local image, so it's not the form upload, but what I'm noticing is it seems to fail even on smaller sized images, so long as they are high in dimensions (panoramas)

Comment: @dangel  you run out of memory, check this site http://www.dotsamazing.com/en/labs/phpmemorylimit
and play with the numbers, 2 gigs is nothing for a lib like GD))

Comment: @vitr, wouldn't it show up in the error logs?  Also I'm now able to get it to fail on only 3MB images

Comment: @dangel are you able to share failed image source? could be many things, I can try to resize it to check if the image is ok

Comment: @vitr,  Interestingly enough it failed when I tried to upload this image to Imgur... https://postimg.org/image/i4dy0ppar/

Comment: @dangel, man, you should zip it, if you want to share the real source, are u a developer?

Comment: @vitr.. what's the point of your question?  that image still fails. did you even try?

Comment: my point is that you provided some processed image via third party service, not the original

Comment: it still failed, so it was a valid link.  The problem is solved, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GD needed to be told to ignore warnings from bad JPEG as apparently GD isn't very tolerant of faulty or broken JPEGs.  These images that were failing were actually created on my phone using the built in panorama tool.  Large images downloaded online or open\saved through photoshop (repaired) were actually just fine after I started testing.

`ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3901885/895810 and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39918.

The problem stemmed from the following lines of Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder.php

```
....
$info = @getimagesize($path);
...

// define core
        switch ($info[2]) {
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $core = @imagecreatefrompng($path);
                break;

            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $core = @imagecreatefromjpeg($path); //<--------here
                dd($core);
                break;
```

I could imagine running into other issues though by completely ignoring warnings.