# Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException Unable to find file ()

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I have this code to save my post images and it returns error of:

```
Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException
Unable to find file ().
```

My code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = 'food' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/');

        Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);


        $food->image = $filename;

      }
```

I've got this code from [Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException using laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195028/intervention-image-exception-notreadableexception-using-laravel-4) but before that i had this code

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = 'food' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/');
        $request->file('image')->move($location, $filename);

        $food->image = $filename;

      }
```

And it worked just fine, the reason I changed my code was to be able to resize images that's all.

Thanks.

Comment: hey you are passing just `$location` in `save()` not the filename as I can compare your two versions

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid even if i use `Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location, $filename);` result is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure that `save()` accepts two parameters try to concat into `$location` if still this problem persists we will look into it..

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid you mean like this? `Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save(public_path('images/'));` if so, the result is same

Comment: no, like this `Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save(public_path('images/'.$filename));`

Comment: same as before `Unable to find file ().`

Comment: ok wait lets dig into this more

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the permissions on Windows/Temp file. Enable read permisson to the users group.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i've managed to get it work by adding this entry in php.ini

```
upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Users\<NAME>\AppData\Local\Temp"
```

and reload the server

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and fixed error. its working fine now.

```
$file = $request->file('image');

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = 'food' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = public_path('images/'. $filename);

    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(800, 400)->save($location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$location = public_path('images/');
$filename = $location. ''.'food' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('800','400')->save($filename);
```

**UPDATE**

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$location = public_path('images/');
Image::make($image)->resize('800','400')->save($location.$filename);
```

Also check [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195028/intervention-image-exception-notreadableexception-using-laravel-4) here it

Comment: `Undefined variable: file`

Comment: yeah I forgot you used `$location` after filename now check it

Comment: can you please point out where you got this error I mean line number?

Comment: ok echo the filename variable I think there must be something wrong in path  and also check if you have used `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: here is my dd($filename)  `"C:\laragon\www\newproject\public\images/food-1506911549.jpg"` and here is my form `<form class="" action="{{route('foods.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: problem is here see a slash before food and image

Comment: hmmm, but that slash is fine if i'm not try to resize image my default code in question.

Comment: `Unable to find file ().`

Comment: I also did this way https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/773 still not working!

Comment: may be it has some permission issues?? have you checked those??

Comment: how? note: I can upload image if not use resize methode.

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalImage = 'images/1.jpg';
Image::make($originalImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try many more, finally i got it.I find out if index.php file use in outside public folder then this problem show. Following this way to solve the problem.

```
    $image = $request->file('image');

    $input['imagename'] = hexdec(uniqid()).$image->getClientOriginalName();

    $location = public_path("upload/image");

    $imgs = Image::make($image->getPathname());

    $imgs->resize(300 , 300, function ($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio(); })->save($location.'/'.$input['imagename']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try many more, finally I got it. Following this code I think solved your problem

```
$location = "assets/images/brand";`
$file = $request->image;
$filename =uniqid().time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image = Image::make(file_get_contents($file))->resize('600','600')->save($location.'/'.$filename);
```